# Mustache Conditions with functions

Tags: javascript, mustache

I want to check in Mustache if a value (not a boolean) is equal to a string. I saw in a random tutorial that you can use a function to define the condition but I haven't seen any documention on the syntax for that. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: The whole point of Mustache is "logic-less templates."  Couldn't you evaluate the equality with Javascript and pass the boolean on to Mustache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Theron said, Mustache is a logic-less templating library and cannot handle conditions (you should use javascript beforehand for that).

If you really want to handle conditional blocks in your templates you should check out http://handlebarsjs.com/.

Comment: Just need to add that Handlebars is also logic-less and you'll need to make a [cheat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional) to implement this functionality

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to simply create a wrapping condition variable that is evaluated outside of the mustache template, as you may already know.

```
var displaySection = false;
if(typeof input == 'string'){
    displaySection=true;
}
```

And then wrap whatever you want to do in a section tag
`{{#displaySection}}`