# Check for a value equals to in Ember Handlebar If block helper

Tags: if-statement, ember.js, handlebars.js

How do we check for a value equality in [ember.js](http://www.emberjs.com)'s If-block helper?

```
{{#if person=="John"}}
```

How do we perform above in handlebars?

Comment: There's also an answer for this question in [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Answer (score 77):

The `{{#if}}` helper can only test for properties, not arbitrary expressions. The best thing to do in cases like this is therefore to write a property computing whatever conditional you want to test for.

```
personIsJohn: function() {
  return this.get('person') === 'John';
}.property('person')
```

Then do `{{#if personIsJohn}}`.

Note: If you find this too limiting, you can also [register your own more powerful `if` helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional).

Comment: @JoLiss Can you pass an arbitrary expression into the computed property from the template?

Comment: No, computed properties cannot take arguments. So you'll need to make a separate CP for every value you want to test for: `personIsJohn`, `personIsMike`, ... Or register a new `if`-like helper -- see my edit above.

Comment: Nice answer. They really need to put this in handlebars.

Comment: Thanks @JoLiss - this is exactly what I needed today to filter out all but one organisation among many.

Comment: Hi Jo, I am trying similar stuff but not successful.sectionfeedIsEqual: (function() {
        {{debugger}}
        return this.get('param1') === this.get('param2');
    }.property('param1', 'param2')
    ) But I dont get values in param1 and param2

Answer (score 26):

Use an [`Ember.Component`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html), thus avoid repetitively defining computed properties in your classes (like `personIsJohn` above):

```
// if_equal_component.js script
App.IfEqualComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isEqual: function() {
    return this.get('param1') === this.get('param2');
  }.property('param1', 'param2')
});

// if-equal.handlebars template
{{#if isEqual}}
  {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

You can define the else part of the comparison, with an `App.ElseEqualComponent`:

```
// else_equal_component.js script
App.ElseEqualComponent = App.IfEqualComponent.extend();

// else-equal.handlebars template
{{#unless isEqual}}
  {{yield}}
{{/unless}}
```

### Usage:

```
{{#if-equal param1=person param2="John"}}
  Hi John!
{{/if-equal}}
{{#else-equal param1=person param2="John"}}
  Who are you?
{{/else-equal}}
```

Answer (score 24):

If you're using HTMLBars (Ember version 1.10+), then you can use the **Ember Truth Helper** addon:

https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers

Once installed, it'll be as simple as this:

```
{{#if (eq person "John")}} hello {{/if}}
```

Comment: can it use without ember-cli?

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander: I haven't tried it without Ember CLI, but I don't see why not.

Comment: This is not in vanilla Handlebars.

Comment: @doublejosh you need to install the truth helper addon. :-)

Answer (score 10):

although this problem can be solved using eq helper by writing

```
{{#if (eq person "John")}} hello {{/if}}
```

but for a general solution you can make your own helper which will take three params `param[0]` and `param[2]` being operand and `param[1]` being operator. Below is the helper file.

compare.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function compare(params) {
  if(params[3]){  //handle case insensitive conditions if 4 param is passed.
    params[0]= params[0].toLowerCase();
    params[2]= params[2].toLowerCase();
  }
  let v1 = params[0];
  let operator = params[1];
  let v2 = params[2];
  switch (operator) {
    case '==':
      return (v1 == v2);
    case '!=':
      return (v1 != v2);
    case '===':
      return (v1 === v2);
    case '<':
      return (v1 < v2);
    case '<=':
      return (v1 <= v2);
    case '>':
      return (v1 > v2);
    case '>=':
      return (v1 >= v2);
    case '&&':
      return !!(v1 && v2);
    case '||':
      return !!(v1 || v2);
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(compare);
```

now you can easily use it for multiple purpose.

for equality check.

```
{{#if (compare person '===' 'John')}} {{/if}}
```

for greater check.

```
{{#if (compare money '>' 300)}} {{/if}}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Jo Liss's answer, you can now do this using a computed property macro for more concise and readable code.

```
personIsJohn: function() {
  return this.get('person') === 'John';
}.property('person')
```

becomes

```
personIsJohn: Ember.computed.equal('person', 'John')
```

[Relavent Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_equal).