# Is it possible to use function in Handlebars #if?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a controller object that's like:

```
MyApp.objController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  init: function(data) {
    data.isValid = function() {
      return (data.validity === "valid");
    }
    this.pushObject(MyApp.MyObj.create(data));
  }
});
```

My view is like:

```
{{#each MyApp.objController}}
  {{#if isValid}}
   <some markup>
   {{else}}
   <some other markup>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I was assuming that the `if` conditional in Handlebars accepts both values and functions, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Is it actually possible, and I'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define your `isValid` as a `property`, you can use it in your `if` statement without creating a custom Handlebars helper, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Dq6ZY/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="obj-template" >
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="age" }}
    {{#if isValid}}
        Si Si.
    {{else}}
        Nope!
    {{/if}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.MyObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    isValid: function() {
        return this.get('age') >= 18;
    }.property('age')
});

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'obj-template',
    controller: App.MyObj.create({
        age: 21
    })
}).append();
```

​

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! Works better than my method of using a `computed` property

Answer (score 11):

Handlebars if statements only compares if a value exists, to if it is a falsy value (ie non-existant, 0, an empty string etc.). You have to write a custom helper function.

You could do it like this

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isValid', function (value, options) {
    if (value == "valid") {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

This registers a block helper. If the value you pass in evaluates to "valid" it returns the template following the the helper with the current data. If it does not evaluate to valid it returns the template following the else statement with the current data.

Then in your template you could use it like this

```
{{#each MyApp.objController}}
    {{#isValid validity}}
        <some markup>
    {{else}}
        <some other markup>
    {{/isValid}}
{{/each}}
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to abide by the spirit of Handlebars and do a 'logic-less' template, set a flag before you render the template indicating whether or not that data is valid, then use the handlebars if helper with the flag.

You could also possible set up a generic function to handle this and other cases. See my answer in [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional/9405113#9405113) for an example for a generic if (similar to the above answer)

Comment: It looks like in Ember 1.5.1+ this is no longer an option.

Comment: Ending in `{{/if}}` didn't work for me, but ending in `{{/isValid}}` did. Not sure if this is because this is 2.5 years later or what, but just wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo. Corrected.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a custom Handlebars helper to do this.

Comment: I was hoping for a bit more detail...I haven't done anything with Handlebars in a month so I've forgotten most of what I knew :P. Will come back and accept this when I go back to that part of my project and try it.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each subsites}}
    {{#if this}}
      <li>{{{WhatIsTheSiteFor this}}}</li>
    {{else}}
      <li>no found</li>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The helper function `WhatIsTheSiteFor`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('WhatIsTheSiteFor', function(siteName) {
  var subSiteName = '',
      siteNameStr = '';

  $.each(siteName, function(i, item) {
    siteNameStr += item;
    return siteNameStr;
  });

  if(siteNameStr === 's.gbin1.com') {
    subSiteName = '<a href="http://' + siteNameStr + '">GB搜索引擎</a>';
  }
  else if (siteNameStr === 'm.gbin1.com') {
    subSiteName = '<a href="http://' + siteNameStr + '">GB手机阅读</a>';
  }
  else if (siteNameStr === 'rss.gbin1.com') {
    subSiteName = '<a href="http://' + siteNameStr + '">RSS消息订阅</a>';
  }

  return subSiteName;
});
```

A demo can be found here: http://www.gbin1.com/gb/networks/uploads/71bb1c1e-0cd3-4990-a177-35ce2612ce81/demo6.html

Comment: Poorly formatted and contextless code. Would be much helpful if explanations are added.