# How can I use Ember Handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Here is my code

```
{{#each dataArray}}
     <li>{{#isTrue idVal1 idVal2}}
    show some text1
 {{else}}
    show some text2
 {{/isTrue}}
    </li>
{{/each}}

Em.Handlebars.registerHelper('isTrue', function(x, y) {
    console.log(x);// shows idVal1
    console.log(y);// shows idVal2 not the exact value, I have passed
    return x==y;
 });
```

Expected Result:- it should return true/false

Comment: refer this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/tutorial/hbs-helper/

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to write bound helpers, issue [#1274](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1274).

I am wondering why this useful pull request still pending.
There is a [workaround](http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2012/08/ember-handlebars-helpers-bound-and-unbound/).