# Double condition with #if

Tags: ember.js

How to do a double condition {{#if person && work}} ?
The && seems not a valid operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe handlebars supports multiple items in the {{#if}} statement (related: [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)).

You could collapse the multiple values in your controller/view into a single computed property and check that single value in the template.  This new computed property will update when either of the original values update:

```
App.ValuesTestController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    value1: false,
    value2: true,
    value1and2: function(){
            return this.get('value1') && this.get('value2');
    }.property('value1', 'value2')
});
```

Your template would look like this:

```
<div>{{#if value1 }}value 1 true{{/if}}</div>
<div>{{#if value2 }}value 2 true{{/if}}</div>
<div>{{#if value1and2 }}value 1 and 2 true{{/if}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if the [@CraigTeegarden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149648/316700) is the elegant one, I have found some cases where this workaround has made my life easier, and therefor it has made me happier:

```
{{#if person}}
  {{#if work}}
    Yeah!
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```