# How to test for undefined Object properties in handlebar.js

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

i have a collection with models with a property called start_time in seconds (0-60..), which is undefined if no start_time is set.

i have troubles to test if this property is 0 or null/undefined, since the handlebar #if always converts it to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fetching the data you could use [collection.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to set a new field on the model that you could test for in your view.

```
YourCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "/api/foo",
  parse: function(res) {        
    return _.map(res, function(source) {    
      obj = _.clone(source);
      obj.no_start = !obj.hasOwnProperty('start_time');
      return obj;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use backbone model defaults?

```
YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        start_time = 'no start time'
    }
});
```

The string should evaluate to true and any null or undefined value will be set to 'no start time' when your model is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little bit of work before calling your template: make `start_time` a string ('0' is true).

You could also register a [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers): see [boolean logic within a handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839375/boolean-logic-within-a-handlebars-template).

Should give something like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_all', function() {
  var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
  var opts = args.pop();

  var fn = opts.fn;
  if(!args[0] && args[0] != 0) fn = opts.inverse;
  return fn(this);
});
```