# Evaluate two conditions in handlebar using ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I was wondering if its possible to do something like this:

```
{{#if ClientController.Client.number && PhoneController.hasLinesToInstall}}
...
{{/if}}}
```

Thanks,

Juanitos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to chain conditions like that in handlebars like that - I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

You could nest them though, like this:

```
{{#if ClientController.Client.number}}
    {{#if PhoneController.hasLinesToInstall}}
        ...
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

That would achieve the same outcome.

Comment: @Juanito - I've been doing some more reading around and I've found a few people saying explicity that it ***isn't*** possible and that it's a design feature of handlebars (forces you to keep your templates clean and free of logic that belongs elsewhere). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional#comment-11152800 http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Comment: Why do we use handlebars if they are so limited? They're a great idea for sure, but i'm a little sad that I have to use so many {{#if}} instead of {{elsif}} and {{#ifCond}} is valid but {{#unlessCond}} isn't

Comment: All of that has been taken care of over the years, 
Never had an issue that handlebars couldn't do something i needed them to do in a nice way.

Answer (score 6):

It's not supported out-of-the-box, but you can use the addon https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers:

```
ember install ember-truth-helpers
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{#if (and ClientController.Client.number PhoneController.hasLinesToInstall)}}
  ...
{{/if}}}
```

Previously, the community's understanding was that templates should be largely free of logic. Overtime, our viewpoint has shifted towards putting more declarative logic in templates-- along with `ember-truth-helpers`, [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) is a great example of this.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked:

```
Ember.computed.and('firstComputedProperty', 'secondComputedProperty')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **ember-template-helpers**
You can use evaluate in your template directly with:

```
{{#if (and ClientController.Client.number PhoneController.hasLinesToInstall)}}
...
{{/if}}}
```