# ember if or statement

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

When using a conditional in ember, is it possible to have an `OR`?

```
{{#if foo OR bar}}
```

or

```
{{#if foo || bar}}
```

There doesn't seem to be anything on it in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/conditionals/).

Comment: Ok, looks like here is the answer, if anyone is looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589624/evaluate-two-conditions-in-handlebar-using-ember

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should move the logic to your controller

```
App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend({
  foo: true,
  bar: false,

  fooOrBar: Em.computed.or('foo', 'bar')
});
```

Leaving the template logic to a minimum

```
{{#if fooOrBar}}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers:

```
ember install ember-truth-helpers
```

Then you can say

```
{{#if (or foo bar)}}
```

Depending on your perspective, [Kingpin2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24810759/1067145) is a bit out of date. Previously, the community's understanding was that templates should be largely free of logic. Overtime, our viewpoint has shifted towards putting more declarative logic in templates-- [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) is a great example of this.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a custom Handlebar helper function to check for conditional operators.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (temp_v1, operator, temp_v2, options) {
var v1,v2;
v1 = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, temp_v1, options);
v2 = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, temp_v2, options);    
switch (operator) {
    case '||':
        return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '&&':
        return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '==':
        return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    default:
        return options.inverse(this);
}
});
```

You can call it in your templates as

```
{{#ifCond foo '||' bar}}
    <div>Conditional helpers works </div>
{{/ifCond}}
```

Comment: This won't work in ember handlebars, it doesn't support block helpers.

Comment: @kingpin2k What i have given is Custom Handlebar Helpers. It can be used in ember handlebars and it will work. Kindly check the jsbin - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/copos/1/

Comment: Doesn't work, it only works the first time, try changing one of the values, it won't recalculate, http://jsbin.com/xijoreya/1/edit

Comment: I have given example for custom ifCondition to check in your template you can add all operators like ( &&, ||, ==, ===, !=, !==, <, <=, >, >=). Have a common method to check for any condition in your template. Here it will not recalculate. Thanks for pointing.