# Implementing if conditions in Mustache template

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

how can we check something like

```
       if( status == 0 ){
            //show pending
       }
       if( status == 1) {
            // show ok
       }
       if( status == 2 ){
            // done
       }
```

this in Mustache Library. Can we provide logic in templates??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mustache template language is explicitly as logic-less as possible.

However, you can use the section construct to do what you want. Add booleans for pending, ok and done to your object, then do:

```
{{#pending}}
// show pending
{{/pending}}

{{#ok}}
// show ok
{{/ok}}

{{#done}}
// show done
{{/done}}
```

This in effect moves the comparison logic to your actual code, which means the template can stay logic-less.

(You mentioned handlebars.js in your tags. If you're using Handlebars, you could theoretically extend the language by doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional), but that kind of goes against the idea of using a logic-less template language. You could even [grab a collection of extensions](https://github.com/elving/swag), but by then I'd recommend going for another template language altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving Moxy-Stencil a try: https://github.com/dcmox/moxyscript-stencil

It is mostly logic-less but has support for helper parameters which seems to address most people's gripes with logic-less templates, eg:

```
{{{isActive home}}}
```

and in the View:

```
view = {
    isActive: function(path: string){ return path === this.path ? "class='active'" : '' }
}
```