# Curious to Knowing The Best Way To Use Handlebars Partials Based On Express Render Variables

Tags: node.js, express, render, handlebars.js

So I'm wondering what is a best way to load a Handlebars Partial in Express when I Have a Render Variable set.

```
app.get('/raves-reviews/corporate-clients', function (req, res) {
    res.render('raves-reviews.html', {  //This of this a micro layout
        layout: 'main',           //this is the main layout
        title: 'Raves & Reviews',
        corporate: true,          //this is part of idea 1
        page: 'corporate-clients' //this is part of idea 2 and 3
    });
});
```

So when a user goes to mysite.com/raves-reviews/corporate-clients, Handlebars will first load the main layout, which I have setup with the navigation to show either the home page slider, or the raves-review slider if its not the home page.

Then it'll load the raves-reviews.html page, which is just a handlebars file that I've renamed the extension to .html, that will be a micro template that will house 4 other pages.

What I don't want to do is have to make 4 pages, with the same raves-reviews.html micro template and have to include each of the other pages as partials. I'd rather make 1 page that will be able to handle every partial it needs like the main layout does with every other page in the website.

So idea 1, is creating 4 {{ #if }} blocks in raves-reviews.html

```
{{#if page1}}
    {{> page1}}
{{/if}}
{{#if page2}}
    {{> page2}}
{{/if}}
{{#if page3}}
    {{> page3}}
{{/if}}
{{#if page4}}
    {{> page41}}
{{/if}}
```

So idea 2 was to use a helper that I found here: [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional) to create the pages, however I did read there that handlebars was suppose to be free of logic. So I'm not really sure if this would even be a good method invoking logic into a templating system that was designed to be used without logic.

Idea 3 was to see if there was a way to use the page variable in app.get to create a partial, but I'm not 100% sure how to pull it off. My original idea was to do:

```
{{> {{page}} }}
```

If there is any other ways I'm totally open to any other ideas. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should probably go with option 1, simply because you already did it

Comment: Yeah maybe i was just over thinking it