# Pass params to a view then to helper in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have 2 views that share a view and I am trying to pass variables between them to turn on|off various html segments.  Is this possible?  When I run console.log the `view.showTitle variable = "view.showTitle"` not 1 like it should be? Odd, right?

view 1 calls view 2 and passes param:

```
{{view "components/social" showTitle="1"}}
```

view 2 tries to pass this param to a helper function:

```
{{#variable-exists view.showTitle}}
  YES
{{else}}
  NO
{{/variable-exists}}
```

the helper being called:

```
export default function(elem,options) {
  if (Ember.isEmpty(elem)) {
    return options.inverse(this);
  } else {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
}
```

I am using the [ember cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) project to build my ember application.

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following these 2 guides [a-way-to-let-users-define-custom-made-bound-if-statements](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/a-way-to-let-users-define-custom-made-bound-if-statements/2583/6) and [custom bound helpers](https://gist.github.com/slindberg/9924116) I was able to adjust my shared views to use this instead of the standard #if statement. This should be more secure than just tossing an #if in there.

```
<li>
    <a href="{{unbound view.varProductSocialBlog}}">
        {{#if-equal view.showDiv "true"}}<div>{{/if-equal}}<i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i>{{#if-equal view.showDiv "true"}}</div>{{/if-equal}}
        {{#if-equal view.showTitle "true"}}Blog{{/if-equal}}
    </a>
</li>
```

I am using the [ember cli](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/a-way-to-let-users-define-custom-made-bound-if-statements/2583/6) project to build my ember application.

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```