# res.send? an express session or local variable, in addition to res.json, to template?

Tags: node.js, templates, express, handlebars.js

I have an API .get call in Node.js that retrieves all of the Messages to a specific user.

```
.get(function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.session.username);

    Models.Message.find( { "to.username": req.session.username } ).exec(function (err, messages) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(messages);

    });
```

These Messages are delivered via res.json(messages); over AJAX to a handlebars templating script.

```
function allTheDocs(resJSON) {

  var templateSource = $("#messagesTemplate").html();

  var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

  var messagesHTML = template({messages: resJSON});

  $('#messages').html(messagesHTML);

}
```

In the script I would like to call a [custom comparison helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9405113), such that if a field:value of the MongoDB data === the session/local variable in node.js -> the templated HTML then renders.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEqual', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if (v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

How would I send either an express session variable (req.session.username) or a local variable (res.locals.username) along with the res.json(messages), to then specifically template the unread Messsages for the session user?

```
{{#each messages}}
    {{#ifEqual to.username req.session.username}}
        {{#if read.marked}
            <div class="unreadMessages">{{../message}}</div>
        {{else}
            <div class="readMessages">{{../message}}</div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Messages are marked unread in a MessageUserSchema that is an embedded array in each Message, so as to account for the option of being sent To any number of users (one to many).

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b203c2cc3060000000eadc"),
    "message" : "Here's a sample Message",
    "to" : [
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53aada6f8b10eb0000ec8a90"),
            "username" : "username1",
            "updated" : ISODate("2014-07-01T05:46:22Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b24b2e35eaa0a4106ca21c"),
            "read" : {
                "marked" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should only pass one object into the view, thus the reason why these are normally called `ViewModel`. Express only accepts one json to be passed as the view model. You can add your info there:

```
Models.Message.find( { "to.username": req.session.username } ).exec(function (err, messages) {

    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    res.json({
         messages : messages,
         sessionUserName: req.session.username
      });

});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each messages.messages}}
    messages.sessionUserName
...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. messages.sessionUserName doesn't render anything though.. console.log(messages.sessionUserName); after the res.json() logs undefined.. And testing the templating with {{#if messages.sessionUserName}}<p>Hello World</p>{{/if}} doesn't render.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: given the code you have above this should work, unless  req.session.username is undefined. Have you tried to output the entire object into the template to see what is there?

Comment: Thanks for that.. Tested in the ajax log, and it was right there, and in the API too.. Realized it was the way I was calling it in the Handlebars script..

Comment: hey, asked this as a separate question because this post was really about express..this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523697/handlebars-helper-to-compare-values-if-v1-v2-and-render-upper-level-scope is about the handlebars part, if you have a chance to take a look..thanks either way

Comment: any thoughts on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523697/handlebars-helper-to-compare-values-if-v1-v2-and-render-upper-level-scope thanks again