# How to pass more then one argument to Ember.js if

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

So I realize that this syntax is not correct but I could achieve this with other handlebars version, what's the Ember.js equivalent of this

```
        {{#if isToday entry_day}}
            Today
        {{else}}
            {{format-entry-date entry_day}}
        {{/if}}
```

Comment: i think you looking for an [if with a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Comment: @igormilla ember doesn't allow that syntax. I am looking for an alternative to that syntax for ember.js