# how to use conditional operators(&& ||) in hbs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hibernate

How to compare two conditions in a IF block.

Example: Like in Java

```
if(apple || orange) {
  ...
}
```

In hbs: it work for single parameter

```
{{#if apple}}
```

how can i compare two parameters in hbs IF block ?
I tried to write

```
{{#if apple || orange}}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Good solution over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional