# meteor tutorial show only the todo belong to the current user (Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional)

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Be patience I'm new at meteor.

I'm following the good getting start tutorial
and just playing around.

Now I want to display
only the todos belong to the current user.

I realized handlebar doesn't have an if expression
statement and I bumped into this useful link

[Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

I've tried with:

### simple-todo.html

```
<template name="task">
  {{#ifCond  owner  Meteor.userId() }}
    <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
      <button class="delete">&times;</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
      <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong> - {{text}}</span>
    </li>
  {{/ifCond}}
</template>
```

### simple-todo.js

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

1) is it the right place to set an handlebar helper ?

but I don't see any todo :(

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: what is `owner` in `{{#ifCond  owner  Meteor.userId() }}` ?

Comment: Handlebars are removed in the meteor latest versions , may i know which version are you working with..??

Comment: @MatiK is a document field   Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date(),            // current time
        owner: Meteor.userId(),           // _id of logged in user
        username: Meteor.user().username  // username of logged in user
      });

Comment: @sitaram9292 Meteor 1.0.2.1

Answer (score 1):

From meteor docs:

> Note that you must use the equals method (or EJSON.equals) to compare them; the === operator will not work. If you are writing generic code that needs to deal with _id fields that may be either strings or ObjectIDs, use EJSON.equals instead of === to compare them.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id

Comment: thanks for the point but like this https://gist.github.com/whisher/16e87f3106c4c308d90b I've got  simple-todos.html:34: Expected space
   ....equals Meteor.userId() }}

Answer (score 0):

Just write a helper to display current users records only.

For displaying records to current user.

```
{{#if currentusertodos}}
<li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
  <button class="delete">&times;</button>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
  <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong> - {{text}}</span>
</li>
{{/if}}
```

You must have userId in the todos collection contains _id of the current user.

```
Template.task.helpers({
currentusertodos:function(){

  return todos.find({userId:Meteor.userId()}).count();
 }
});
```

In this way you can do it

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Ok but this way if an user is logged can see all the todos also those belong to other users ..... it's not my question

Comment: Ok the just write a helper which brings the current user todos only.??

Comment: @Whisher just check my updated answer and you need to write some more helpers according to your requirements.

Comment: I'v thought quite the same but the helper miss a field the 'owner' so no comparison I mean in the help should be a comparision between the current user and the todo owner

Comment: @Whisher I hope it has helped you.