# Ember conditions in views

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple blog in which I learn Ember.
Now I have a controller

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['originalId:desc']
  sortedPosts: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),
})
```

So in template I show all posts. For this I want to show edit link near all of my posts.
So question is how to do this in handlebars.

I want to do something like this:

```
{{#each post in sortedPosts}}
  <h1>{{link-to post.title 'post' post }}</h1>

  {{#if session.isAuthenticated and post.ownedBy(session.user)}} <!--This place doesn't work-->
    {{link-to 'Edit' 'post.edit' post }}
  {{/if}}

  {{{post.text}}}
  <hr/>
{{/each}}
```

I found this question [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional) but I hope that there is better solution.

P.S.: There is one more question about sorting with [SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html). It doesn't reload templates when `sortProperties` is changed. So I have to create one more property `sortedPosts`. Maybe someone knows why it doesn't work?

Comment: You better use computed properties in handlebars template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a computed property in the controller and then use it in the view. If you have 2 computed properties and want to combine them into a 3rd - you can use `computed.and` (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_and))

Comment: How can I do this? Who can this property be in controller for each object?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for itemController - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Comment: Thx, it's exactly what I need. Can I render different tempaltes depending on computed property?