# Helper broken in Ember 1.10

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I was using custom Handlebars helper extending the functionality of 'if' block.

In Ember 1.10 this doesnt work anymore as there is no Ember.Handlebars.bind property which allowed binding to the property....

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (a, b, options) {
    return Ember.Handlebars.bind.call(options, contexts[0], a, options, true, function(result) {
        return result === b
    });
});
```

The usage would be:

```
{{#ifCond property "value"}}
    {{some-other-component}}
{{else}}
    something other...
{{/ifCond}}
```

but this returns an error "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Is there any way that I can bind to passed properties in helper? I cannot use registerBoundHelper because it doesn't support having child blocks...
I wanted to use Component instead of helper but then I cannot use the {{else}} block...

This solution for the helper was previously taken from [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually managed to find a way to do it, so I'll write the answer for my own question...

Instead of using undocumented hacks, I used the proposed change: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10295

So my helper looks like this now:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('isSame', function(value1, value2) {
    return value1 === value2
});
```

and the usage:

```
{{#if (isSame property "value")}}
    {{some-other-component}}
{{else if (isSame property "otherValue"}}
    something other...
{{else}}
    something other...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but where in the whole project should I register the helper? Havin a lot of problems with this old version emberjs

Comment: I was using it just in helpers folder, but that wasn't ember-cli environment.