# How to write Helpers in HTMLBars?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, htmlbars

After the latest release of EmberJS `v1.9.0` I am trying to move from Handlebars to HTMLbars. What I am finding very challenging is lack of documentation.

I am trying to implement very simple helpers.

For example take this handlebars helpers:

### HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{logIt test}}
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>
</script>
```

### JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#main'
});

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller){
            controller.set('test', 'mytest');
        }
    });

    Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper("logIt", function(something) {
        console.log(something);
    });
```

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sisir/p463q2L8/

How do I convert it to htmlbars?

Comment: Fiddle update to Ember 1.10, with HTMLBars still works - http://jsfiddle.net/qj6v3vuf/ - I don't know what are the plans of Ember team but maybe even if you are using the Ember.Handlebars namespace - internally this is directed to HTMLBars. The only method I see in HTMLBars is Em.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper, which is documented as private. Even new method, which I marked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558696/helper-broken-in-ember-1-10, is in Handlebars namespace... So maybe just let's go with old ways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Ember 1.13, there are two APIs: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_new-ember-js-helper-api

The simplest and more common syntax is now this:

```
export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(params, hash) {
  return params.join(' ');
});
```

> Helpers receive two arguments: params are the ordered params passed to a helper, and hash contains the key-value options, for example title="Mr.".

Answer (score 4):

<del>As of Ember 1.10.0, this question is solved by doing `Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(theHelperFunction)`.</del>

**Edit:** since Ember 1.13.6 (July 31, 2015), using this is flagged as deprecated.

> DEPRECATION: Using Ember.HTMLBars._registerHelper is deprecated. Helpers (even dashless ones) are automatically resolved. [deprecation id: ember-htmlbars.register-helper]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use **Ember.Handlebars.helper** which is what is in the latest [emberjs guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/). This [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dakecocaro/1/edit) uses htmlbars and it works. This is the helper in the **jsbin**

```
AppLogItHelper = Ember.Handlebars.helper("logIt", function(something){
  console.log(something);
});
```

If you are using **ember-cli** it will auto generate one for you but that uses **Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper** which doesn't work in the jsbin but works in my ember-cli app.

Comment: Since Ember 1.10.1 should use Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper

Answer (score 0):

Very an important novelty is **HTMLBars have subexpression**! Since Ember 1.10+ was switched to HTMLBars and you should use Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper instead  `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper`. But you can still use `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` from Ember 1.10.1 version

New approach:

```
App.XEqHelper = Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(function(params, hash, options, env) {
    return params[0] === params[1];
    });
```

it call from templates as:

```
{{#if (x-eq order 'delivery_order')}}
    Need a delivery
{{/if}}
```