# meteor create custom 'if/else'

Tags: javascript, meteor

I haven't used meteor for a while, back in the day I was able to create custom handlebars helpers like

```
{{#ifCond this.a "a"}}
   ...
{{else}}
   ...
{{/ifCond}}
```

and define a helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Example from this SO Question:
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Since meteor introduced new spacebars features this doesn't seem to work anymore, anybody any ideas?

I think it has something to do with this:
"Custom Block Helpers" : [Spacebars docu](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#custom-block-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

This was the closest I could get, but it's not too bad:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});


{{#if ifCond this.Equipment '==' 'Assistive'}}
true
{{else}}
false
{{/if}}
```