# Handlebars each from a custom start point

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, handlebars.js, each

Say I have an object,

```
      {
        "empID": "1002729041",
        "empName": "ABHIJIT AUDHYA"
      },
      {
        "empID": "1004563331",
        "empName": "ABDUL MULLA"
      },
      {
        "empID": "1004703190",
        "empName": "ABDUL RAZIC"
      },
      {
        "empID": "1004912437",
        "empName": "ABDUL HAFEEZ"
      }
```

I can use handlebars to loop through the entire object using,

```
{{#each myObj}}
  <li>{{empName}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Say, I want to start from the 3rd object, ignoring the 1st and 2nd. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: json array is in sorted order

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention that it is a `JSON` array. I am not sure if it will be in a sorted order. I don't think it will be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pavanastechie/L6798/6/

Comment: Hey if you like it i will add the answer

Comment: In helper code you are checking the conditions statically using my data. It wont work if the object is different. Anyway I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need a helper for that:
[Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

So you could do something like `if index > 2 then show content`.

If I may ask: why not drop the first two (or for that matter: any unneeded elements) in actual javascript before calling the template?

Edit: here you are...

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachFrom', function(context, count, options) {
    var ret = "";
    
    context.slice(count).forEach(function(elem) {
        ret += options.fn(elem);
    });
    
    return ret;
});

var context = {
    myObj: [{
        "empID": "1002729041",
            "empName": "ABHIJIT AUDHYA"
    }, {
        "empID": "1004563331",
            "empName": "ABDUL MULLA"
    }, {
        "empID": "1004703190",
            "empName": "ABDUL RAZIC"
    }, {
        "empID": "1004912437",
            "empName": "ABDUL HAFEEZ"
    }]
};

var source = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#container").append(template(context));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/handlebarsjs/3.0.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{#eachFrom myObj 3}}
          <li>{{empName}}</li>
        {{/eachFrom}}
    </ul>
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I have ten list items out of which it should display only two. I have a `see more` button. On clicking `see more`, I should show the remaining list items in a separate pop-up. I can do it using `JS`, but I was curious to know if this was possible in handlebars. It seemed very straight forward to me. Sad it is not there by default. I don't need to show it on an if condition. I am asking if I can display it from the third object straight away without any if block? Is there a helper for that?

Comment: A simple `array.slice()` can solve this... added it to my answer.

Comment: This looks like a more dynamic solution. I am accepting it. Hope this will work irrespective of my data.

Comment: Well, it needs to be an array (or an object which returns an array after calling slice ;) ), than this works!