# Using logical operators in Meteor's Spacebars

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

Is it possible to use logical operators in Spacebars (without template helpers)?

For example:

```
{{#if status == '0'}}
      Hello world.
{{/if}}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
   While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
   client/views/test.html:46: Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, null, or a sub expression enclosed in "(", ")"
   ...       {{#if status == '0'}}             ...
   ^

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16315366/266561

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spacebars can't into comparison, but you can use native [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for it. Register it on client with:

```
Template.registerHelper('_', function(){
  return _;
});
```

and then use it like this:

```
{{_.isEqual status 0}}
```

It return `true` if status is 0 or `false` otherwise.