# Handle conditions in Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using Ember with Handlebars template

How can I get the following support in Handlebars ?

```
{{#if response.someCount> 0}}
```

Would I have to add some mapping attribute in Controller to achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional

Answer (score 0):

You need helper for that, for example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function (lvalue, rvalue, options) {
    if (arguments.length < 3)
      throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");
    operator = options.hash.operator || "==";
    var operators = {
      '==': function (l, r) {
        return l == r;
      },
      '===': function (l, r) {
        return l === r;
      },
      '!=': function (l, r) {
        return l != r;
      },
      '<': function (l, r) {
        return l < r;
      },
      '>': function (l, r) {
        return l > r;
      },
      '<=': function (l, r) {
        return l <= r;
      },
      '>=': function (l, r) {
        return l >= r;
      },
      'typeof': function (l, r) {
        return typeof l == r;
      }
    }
    if (!operators[operator])
      throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator " + operator);
    var result = operators[operator](lvalue, rvalue);
    if (result) {
      return options.fn(this);
    } else {
      return options.inverse(this);
    }
  });
```

And then in Your template:

```
{{#compare response.someCount 0 operator = ">"}}
// Some code...
{{/compare}}
```

Sorry can't remember from where I toot that code, but it runs flawlessly in one project for over the year.

Comment: Thx...I just tried adding it as bower dependency...However am getting error...Assertion Failed: A helper named 'gt' could not be found

Comment: so do i have to also import or register the addon somewhere ?

Comment: you only need to install it with `ember install ember-truth-helpers` and then it's ready to be used.

Comment: `Handlebars.registerHelper` has been deprecated, use [Ember.Helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html#method_helper) instead.