# Portable expression language with PHP and JavaScript bindings?

Tags: javascript, php, dsl

I work with a web application that uses heavy mix of server-side PHP and client-side Javascript, and I would like to allow administrators to configure some basic conditionals. For example, we might have a data model with:

```
var person = {
  name: 'Alice',
  age: 33,
  favorite_color: 'purple',
  address: {street: '123 Some St', state: 'NY'}
};
```

An administrator might want to hide a field or trigger an action based on a conditional like:

```
((person.age > 20) or (person.favorite_color == 'red')) and (person.address.state == 'NY')
```

Ideally, we could use the same conditionals in different contexts -- such as client-side validation *and* server-side validation.

If the application were *only* server-side PHP, or if it were full-stack JS, then you could use PHP `eval()` or JS `eval()`. But for an application that involves multiple languages, this doesn't work. It seems like one would need to create a small DSL with implementations for different platforms, eg

```
// JS
var condition = "(person.age > 20) or (person.favorite_color == 'red')";
var isMatch = ExpressionLanguage.eval(condition, {
  person: {...}
})

// PHP
$condition = "(person.age > 20) or (person.favorite_color == 'red')";
$isMatch = ExpressionLanguage::eval($condition, array(
  'person' => array(...),
));
```

I've encountered [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), which takes a similarly portable approach to templating. However, its design is specifically "logic-less" and does not support conditions. Never-the-less, it seems like a common enough problem. How have others addressed the desire for portable conditionals?

Comment: Note that an expression language can also be safer than JS/PHP `eval()` because it doesn't allow arbitrary code execution.... and it's not even Turing-complete.

Comment: [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is a superset of mustache, would that work for you? I use that across PHP/Javascript projects and am pretty happy with it.

Comment: Ooh, that's a neat idea. Unfortunately, some quick searching suggests that it doesn't natively support common conditional notations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional

Comment: There may not be an answer... started thinking about how to do it myself... https://gist.github.com/totten/ce37971dfdd029c40b08 ...

Answer (score 2):

Was faced with a similar issue of handling expressions on my client-side, but also being able to understand those same expressions on the server-side.

Stumbled upon a [JS port](https://github.com/jameskfry/expression-language) of the [Symfony Expression Language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) for PHP. Seems to be very robust and have not had any issues so far.