# BigCommerce Stencil & Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

Is there a custom helper available in Stencil to chain multiple conditions rather than nest them?

```
{{#if template_file '!==' 'pages/home'}}
{{#if template_file '!==' 'pages/product'}}
{{#if template_file '!==' 'pages/category'}}
...

{{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Can the 'any' helper be used in this instance?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do that requires a "chain" as opposed to nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

In short, no. You are better off writing your own helper if you plan on using this condition more than once. But then again, maybe it would be better to just declare a global variable on the current page, and then on your 'dynamic' template file, you can have a single conditional statement that compares that single variable?

Does that make sense? Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `or` statement. For example:

```
{{#or (if template_file '===' 'path/to/file') (if template_file '===' 'path/to/file')}} 
    <html>/{{component(s) to render}}
    {{else}}
        {{#or (if template_file '===' 'path/to/file') (if page.title '===' 'Page Title')}}
    <html>/{{component(s) to render}}
        {{else}}
    <html>/{{component(s) to render}}
    {{/or}}{{/or}}
```