# Handlebars - Access Navigator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am modifying parts of the Ghost blog to use different languages. For that, I am writing a Handlebars helper:

```
hbs.registerHelper("language", function () {
        var lang = (navigator.language) ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;  
        return lang;
    });
```

However, I get an error where the message is `navigator is undefined`. Ghost is using `express-hbs`, so I am guessing it has something to do with the custom flavor, because the same helper [was declared here](https://gist.github.com/tracend/3261055).

What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: I think your code is running at server.navigator is global in browser.

Comment: @gujefers so what would be the proper way to tweak the code above to reference the right instance?

Comment: Render it at browser,or get the language from Session Object(maybe Request)

Comment: @gujefers To clarify, the purpose of this is to pass it into a view, where I can get the language before it renders the content in the browser. So ultimately I would want to get it in the helper. Any thoughts on doing that?

Comment: Be careful with this approach - I definitely wouldn't recommend it as a general approach to handling multiple languages. You remove the ability to have a caching layer in front of your blog (the cache will store whatever the language the first visitor to a page requests) and unless you are redirecting to a language-specific page you are also opening yourself to google penalties. Google has some details on how to properly handle multi-language sites - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after a late night of coding.

In `index.js`, within the `renderPost` function, I can (in a very primitive way) query the client language:

`response.post.language = req.headers["accept-language"].substring(0,5).toLowerCase();`

This will create a new property within the `post` object. With the help of a [custom conditional helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16315366/303696) (placed in `helpers.js`):

```
{{#ifCond language '==' 'en-us'}}
     {{content lang="1"}}
{{else}}
     {{content lang="2"}}
{{/ifCond}}
```

In `core\server\helpers\content.js` I've already implemented a custom language parser that displays the right content depending on the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLanguage(req){
    ....
}
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        showTitle: true,

        helpers: {
            language: function () { return getLanguage(req); }
        }
    });
});
```