# Handlebars: multiple conditions IF statement?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js

I didn't find this was possible in Handlebars... I need something like this:

```
{{#if A || B || C}} something {{/if}}
```

Is that possible to achieve? I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional), but as I need for 3 variables (A, B, C) I don't really know how to apply it. Any ideas?

Comment: It's the same idea as with 2 parameters. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21915381/5743988) would allow you to use any JS expression.

Answer (score 36):

They do not have multiple conditions.
But you can achieve it by nesting. This works:

```
{{#if A}}
   {{#if B}}
     {{#if C}}
       something 
    {{/if}}
   {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks @BarlasApaydin

Comment: this handles {{#if A && B && C}} but not {{#if A || B || C}} really to achieve the "or" scenario it would be {{#if A}}something{{/if}}{{#if B}}something{{/if}}{{#if C}}something{{/if}} but that's not as DRY (don't repeat yourself) because you have to repeat "something" 3 times, where "something" could be a large chunk of code.

Comment: The answer to this question solves it directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: how does this answer equivalent to
  {{#if A || B || C}} something {{/if}}
?

isn't it equivalent to
  {{#if A && B && C}} something {{/if}}
?

Answer (score 7):

What about this?

```
{{#if A}}
  something
{{else if B}}
  someting B
{{else if C}}
  someting C
{{/if}}
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer as it gives an alternative solution when the OR-functionality is not implemented in the language

Answer (score 2):

in 3.0 you can do it with

```
{{#if A}}
  something
  {{else if B}}
    something
    {{else if C}}
      something
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

if you use something below 3.0 you can make multiple ifs

```
{{#if A}}
{{else}}
  {{#if B}}
```

... and so on hope this helps