# How can I check multiple conditions in a Handlebars template?

Tags: html, arrays, json, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

I have a handelbars page where depending on the title item in json it'll show different content.

so far this is built using **helper if_wq**

for example **if title = test** this works

I would like a way to extend this functionality to show **if title = test** and **colors.href = /test**

so the condition is only valid if both conditions are true.

**example of my code**

```
 {{#if_eq title 'test'}}
        True
    {{/if_eq}}
```

**Example of my helper task**

```
handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a === b) {
        return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

**example of my json**

```
"range-list-page": {     
  "ranges": [            
    {                    
    "title": "test",  
  "colors": [                                               
    {                                                       
      "color": "#fff",                                      
      "label": "White",                                     
      "bordered": true,                                     
      "href" : "/test"      
    },                                                      
    {                                                       
      "color": "#F3DCAE",                                   
      "label": "Cream",                                     
      "href" : "http://google.com"                          
    },                                                      
    {                                                       
      "color": "#C5B7B0",                                   
      "label": "Cashmere",                                  
      "href" : "http://google.com"                          
    },                                                      
    {                                                       
      "color": "#D0B193",                                   
      "label": "Larch",                                     
      "href" : "http://google.com"                          
    }                                                       
  ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars: multiple conditions IF statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251635/handlebars-multiple-conditions-if-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following helper methods that I define:

(1) `eq` - you already have that,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eq', function(a, b) {
    if(a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

(2) `and` - See important note below.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('and', function () {
    // Get function args and remove last one (meta object); every(Boolean) checks AND
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, arguments.length - 1).every(Boolean);
});
```

NOTE: As you can see, I have to remove the last arg from `arguments` before doing `Array.prototype.slice.call` because the last arg returned here is a meta object. If you don't trim the last result of arguments then `every(Boolean)` will give wrong results. Otherwise it's just an `every(Boolean)`.

(3) Now, assuming we have these 2 helpers, the following example works to check AND/EQ:

```
{{#if (and (eq var1 'STRING1') (eq var2 'STRING2') ) }}
...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: hmm seem to get error TypeError in plugin 'gulp-compile-handlebars'
Message:
    ((helpers.title || (depth0 && depth0.title)) || alias2).call is not a function

Comment: Strange, does Gulp somehow change this suggestion? Are you using a specific version of Handlebars? Mine is this: `Handlebars v4.0.11` `handlebars.min.js`. I am not using Gulp.

Comment: good point, ill check and accept the answer if its a problem like that, thanks

Comment: One more thing, check how you're calling the `{{#if}...`, check all parentheses. Note the order and how different clauses are grouped above.