# Render two variables at the same time inside div

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

How can I render the values of two variables `{{item_link}}` and `{{item_value}}` inside the same div class?

I am using the `#if` helper to conditionally render the block. If I render them separately I am able to evaluate them, but if I try doing something like `{{#if item_link && item_value}}`, so I can then use them inside the div, it does not work. These are Handlebars layout templates. Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it why you need that `#if`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Comment: also [Handlebars: multiple conditions IF statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251635/handlebars-multiple-conditions-if-statement)

Comment: I think nesting the `#if`s would be the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, at least in my case. Sorry ...

Comment: Yes, and applied it. But things you know do not work all the time, even if another accepted SO answer says so. I followed exactly the logic nesting the {{#if ..}} but for a reason it was not working on my case. Now trying to see how they can render by removing the conditional. But the links you suggested doesn't work. Sorry

Comment: Then you'll need to post more context, because with the given information simple nesting of `#if`s works fine

Comment: Now, thats a good suggestion, whereas in the previous comment I sensed a little aggressivenes. Let me debug further and see why this is happening so I can add more feedback in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example with nested `#if`s: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/kf60d8pz/

Comment: Thanks @76484 for your kindness to provide an example. Still does not work in my case. I solved it in another way. I will post the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I found. I moved the AND logic inside my js file and created a single object `object = {item_link_name: item_link_value, item_value_name: item_value_value}`. This way I can effectively html render with `{{object}}` or with `{{#if object}} ... {{/if}}` (if I need also to have some additional logic in my html, modulo the one included in my js) and refer to the individual values with `{{item_link_value}}` and `{{item_value_value}}`.

Answer (score -2):

You can render the values inside the same div by concatenating them using the {{concat}} helper:

```
<div class="my-class">
  {{concat item_link item_value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Klone, thank you for your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what "doesn't seem to work" means ? How is it not working exactly ?

Comment: Nothing is rendered.

Comment: concat is not a built in helper (and doesn't help with the question which is about logical operators in an if block)

Comment: The question is "How can I render the values of two variables {{item_link}} and {{item_value}} inside the same div class? "

Comment: Did you read the question @Klone ? or just the title? And any way you can just `<div>{{item_link}} {{item_value}}</div>`, but the OP wants to conditionally render the block based on the truthiness of the two variables (amply covered by the two flagged duplicates).