# Meteor templates, check if with or

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to check a condition with or. how is it possible?

```
  {{#if  $.Session.equals 'showField' 'edit'}}
```

or

```
 {{#if  $.Session.equals 'showField' 'add'}}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional). I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: consider to install this ? https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers and use $or a b

Comment: both of them is correct. thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blueren and Iiro said:

```
 {{#if or  ($.Session.equals 'showField' 'edit') ($.Session.equals 'showField' 'add') }}
```

Then in clien/helpers folder make a js file and put this:

```
Template.registerHelper('or',(a,b)=>{
  return a || b;
});
```