# Handlebar helper in nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I need to attach if condition in my handlebar template which checks the equality of string. I have registered a handlebar helper in my script file and using that within my templates. Following is my code.

**Test.js file**

```
"use strict"

const handlebars = require('handlebars');

const writeSourceFile = (filename, type) =>
    new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
        fs.writeFile(filename, type, function(err) {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve();
        }));

handlebars.registerHelper('is_status', function(msg, matchMsg, options)
{
    if(msg === matchMsg)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});

const tpl = handlebars.compile(fs.readFileSync('resources/my.html.hbs').toString('utf-8'));

fs.writeFileSync('/home/malintha/tracks.html', tpl(dm));

console.log("Generated source")

res.end();

..............
```

**my.html.hbs file**

```
{{#is_status (location this "mylocation")}}yes{{/is_status}}
```

I am not getting any output due to an error which is not obvious to me. My template is working fine without this custom is_status check.

What is the problem with my helper or template? Appreciate your insight.

Comment: Could you please share the link to the source code, if possible ? It is hard to make out the context of, or replicate what you're trying to achieve, for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning `true` or `false` in your helper, try returning `options.fn(this)` or `options.inverse(this)`.

And, try calling it in your .hbs file with

`{{#is_status location "mylocation"}}yes{{/is_status}}`

[Here](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) is an example of this being done in the documentation.
Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16315366/5442849) is a really helpful stackoverflow answer of a more flexible way to compare variables.