# Basic 'if' statements do not work in handlebars JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-statements, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am using `express-handlebars` and have the following minimal template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        {{#if page === 'help'}}YAAAY{{/if}}

    </body>
</html>
```

This fails to parse with:

```
Error: C:\Users\mike\myapp\views\error.hbs: Parse error on line 6:
...ody>     {{#if page === 'help'}}YAAAY{{/i
---------------------^
```

I understand handlebars isn't expecting an `===`, but isn't that the point of `if`?

How can I use an `if` statement in handlebars?

Comment: Try `==` instead.

Comment: Handlerbars have if only for checking if value is true or false it's not if like in javascript for this you will need to created your own helper.

Comment: Wow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16315366/1225328. I'm curious to know the reasoning behind this "no boolean operator" choice they made to be honest.

Comment: @sp00m care to post another answer with this link or edit my answer? Think it's very helpful in this context ;-)

Comment: @lustoykov Feel free to edit your answer, I don't have much credits here :) The best might actually be to mark this question as duplicate, what do you think @mikemaccana?

Comment: @sp00m Views should be as dumb as possible. Computation should be done elsewhere.

Comment: @DaveNewton Makes sense, looks like the above link actually breaks this principle... What would then be a better approach for the OP's case in your opinion? Also, one could ask why views have `if`s in the first place then... Looks like having entirely logicless views is a bit utopian (depending on the definition of "logic") :)

Comment: @sp00m There's an `if`, it's already not logic-less. The point is to minimize the amount of computation in views, as it's almost always easier to test that logic outside of templates (and that logic has a tendency to accrete, making it even harder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handlebar's `if-helper` [only accepts a boolean as an argument](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html). You have two options:

### Use the existing handler

Pass the result from `page === 'help'` as a variable in the template and do something like:

```
{{#if isPageHelp}}
  <h1> Help! </h1>
{{/if}}
```

### Make your own handler

You can [implement the `===` operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16315366/1225328) with your own handler. Thanks [@sp00m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225328/sp00m).

Comment: That seems like a massive amount of work: `isPageHelp`, `isPageAbout`, `isPageBlog`, for n pages. Is there a better way?

Comment: writing another helper that better fits your needs? :) I agree with you though - it's not the most pleasant API to work with.

Comment: This is one reason I prefer Nunjucks to Handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

Try this helpers

```
 const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
    Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1,v2,options) {
    if (v1 == v2)
        return options.fn(this);
    else
        return options.inverse(this);
    });

Handlebars.registerHelper('exCond', function (v1,v2,options) {
    if (v1 != v2)
        return options.fn(this);
    else
        return options.inverse(this);
});
```