# Can't use logical operators in handlebars #if statement?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following code:

```
{{#if true}} An {{else}} A {{/if}
```

That's the entire template. It's loading fine. But notice the `#if` condition is simply `true`. If I put anything other than a literal there, it doesn't work. Any variable I put, any sort of programmatic expression like `{{#if 3 > 5}}`, it gives me a Parser Error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 36:
{{#if 3 > 5 }} An {{else}} A
---------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

I can't figure that out. I even reduced it to just `{{#if 3 > 5}} A {{/if}}` and it still gives a parser error.

So I thought maybe you have to use a helper for this sort of thing, but I can't get any helper I register to work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operator in a handlebars.js {{#if}} conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `#if` helper can only test for properties to be true or false – not arbitrary expressions[[source](https://emberigniter.com/how-to-equals-conditional-comparison-handlebars/)], so you have to do everything with helpers. Just write a function to compare things with logical operators and return `true` or `false`.

And to save you some trouble, the syntax for calling helpers doesn't use parentheses, either....arguments are space-separated like in rails. So it looks like:

```
{{myHelperFunction myarg1 myarg2}}
```

And if you want to nest helpers, you need parens:

```
{{myOuterHelper (myInnerHelper myarg1 myarg2)}}
```

Last tip from me, if you want to nest your helper with an `#if`, you need parens, too:

```
{{#if (myHelper myarg1 myarg2)}} content {{/if}}
```